# adding ListView children to a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

i have a HorizontalScrollView, and i am adding a bunch of ListView as its children. my XML file looks something like the following. for brevity, i will omit some of the attributes.

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

in my java code, i then populate the ListView with data. If there is only 1 or 2 records, the ListView does not extend all the way to the bottom of the screen. i see what seems to be a transparent background. how do i get rid of this behavior.

i also tried using this component from http://www.matt-reid.co.uk/blog_post.php?id=62. again, i have the same problem.

any help is appreciated.

below is the XML file. i've simply copied/pasted the control code into my package as demo.fling8.HorizontalPager.

```
 <demo.fling8.HorizontalPager 
android:id="@+id/hp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <TextView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text= "Etiam et dui volutpat purus gravida consequat. Nullam sodales velit a nunc pretium ut tempor urna molestie. Maecenas metus enim, venenatis vel volutpat non, iaculis ut justo. Nulla venenatis malesuada quam at tincidunt. Nunc at sem eros, convallis eleifend arcu. Curabitur gravida velit nec nunc condimentum feugiat. In ultrices orci sit amet purus fermentum placerat in et lacus. Praesent sit amet sodales lectus. Morbi vehicula condimentum purus eu vulputate. Morbi risus enim, rhoncus a iaculis et, porta vitae justo." 
    />
<ListView android:id="@+id/lv" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
 </demo.fling8.HorizontalPager>
```

in my MainActivity.java class, this is my code to populate the ListView.

```
 List<MyObject> dataList = DataAccessService.getDummyData();
 ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
 listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.id.textViewTitle, dataList));
```

if you "fling" or "swipe", you will notice that the TextView does not suffer from this effect of having a transparent background (the whole screen is black). when you fling to the ListView, if there are only a few rows, then from where the ListView ends to the bottom of the screen, there is a transparent background.

here is a link to the project file: http://www.box.net/shared/5pybcpj8mkbfhv3j3ach. please let me know if you cannot access it. if you deploy to your device you should see the effect (of a transparent background).

here is a link to another project file: http://www.box.net/shared/i9vs6yq9j2s4ysp994et. this project file uses only a HorizontalScrollView (not the component referenced above). as you will probably observe, there is the transparent background.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, if you just want a background, set it in your horizontal LinearLayout.

Comment: Is your problem the transparent background or the ListView not extending all the way to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @Jack the problem is with the transparent background. when the ListView has like 30 or 100 rows, it extends way past the visible screen height, and when i scroll to the bottom of the ListView, i don't see that transparent background. when the ListView has like 1-2 items (or a few items), then its height/rows stops in the middle of the screen, and from that point to the bottom of the screen, there is the transparent background.

Comment: @Dan i have set the background to Black, still, it doesn't help. i've also set the HorizontalScrollView and single child LinearLayout's backgrounds to Black too, still, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to implement horizontal paging see the `ViewPager` widget in the compatibility library: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html It works all the way back to devices running Android 1.6. It also allows you to only keep a few pages "live" at any given time, keeping your view hierarchy much simpler and allowing you to work with large data sets.

Comment: i highly recommend this approach of using the compatibility library (version 4, revision 3). the com.example.android.supportv4.app.FragmentPagerSupport has a really good demo. they don't use the ViewPager class directly, but "horizontal paging" with a ListView child (for each page) is clearly  demonstrated. thanks a lot for saving me the headache.

Comment: Glad it helped! :) We've had a lot of requests for a widget like this and we're glad that we were finally able to make it available to developers.

Answer (score 1):

You may omit HorizontalScrollView as ListView automatically expand and if  there is no room it Scroll automatically. Simply use

```
    <LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no, i need the HorizontalScrollView, as far as I can tell. i need to implement the UI effect of fling/swipe left to right (and right to left) with a new view each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but it might

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i said i've omitted some attributes. :) still, it doesn't work.