# How to make vertically Scrollable row in a horizontal ListView

Tags: android

I want to implement Android Horizontal list view with Vertically scrollable content in each row . Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Horizontal listview inside vertical listview (and scrolling multiple listviews together)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715341/horizontal-listview-inside-vertical-listview-and-scrolling-multiple-listviews-t)

A horizontal list view can contain each item inside a vertical scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon how you are planning to make each row, in XML or programatically.
Either way you just need to put your `View` or `Layout` for row in a `ScrollView` and fix a height for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Custom list view.
Below is the Code : You have to put the Listview inside the Horizontal Scroll View :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageViewseparatorListview"
            android:id="@+id/hor">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relcoll"
                android:background="@drawable/wallpapertheme">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                    android:id="@+id/textviewoutletname"
                    android:text="@string/textviewoutletname"
                    android:layout_width="180dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/listview_heading_background" />



                <ImageView
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderSeperator"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewseparator1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textviewoutletname" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                    android:id="@+id/textviewcashamount"
                    android:text="@string/textviewcashamount"
                    android:layout_width="90dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewseparator1"
                    android:background="@drawable/listview_heading_background" />

                <ImageView
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderSeperator"
                    android:id="@+id/CollectionBarSeparator1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textviewcashamount" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                    android:id="@+id/textviewchequeamount"
                    android:text="@string/textviewchequeamount"
                    android:layout_width="90dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/CollectionBarSeparator1"
                    android:background="@drawable/listview_heading_background" />

                <ImageView
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderSeperator"
                    android:id="@+id/CollectionBarSeparator2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textviewchequeamount" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                    android:id="@+id/textviewosamount"
                    android:text="@string/textviewosamount"
                    android:layout_width="105dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/CollectionBarSeparator2"
                    android:background="@drawable/listview_heading_background" />



                <ListView
                    style="@style/ListViewTheme"
                    android:id="@+id/listviewcollection"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textviewosamount"></ListView>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Listview.xml

```
**Second.XML**
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@style/ListViewTextViewParent">

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListViewTextView"
        android:id="@+id/textviewoutletname"
        android:text="Mayur"
        android:layout_width="180dip" />

    <ImageView
        style="@style/ListViewTextSeperatorForAll"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewseparator1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListViewTextView"
        android:id="@+id/textviewcashamount"
        android:text="2001"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="90dip" />

    <ImageView
        style="@style/ListViewTextSeperatorForAll"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewseparator1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListViewTextView"
        android:id="@+id/textviewchequeamount"
        android:text="3000"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <ImageView
        style="@style/ListViewTextSeperatorForAll"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewseparator1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListViewTextView"
        android:id="@+id/textviewosamount"
        android:text="5000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="100dip" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Now extend class by the Base Adapter In your activity And Inflate second .xml file.

And If You want you can take reference of below link also :

[adding ListView children to a HorizontalScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060343/adding-listview-children-to-a-horizontalscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

create one vertical scroll view

add that view to your horizontal scroll view